# Flutter - Command line - Emulator- Device not found

Tags: dart, flutter

Disclaimer - Newbie

Just DL everything needed to get started with Flutter on my Windows 10 pc.

Flutter sdk -saved to a folder on my desktop 
Git Google USB Driver
Visual Studio Code and its Flutter/Dart plug-ins 
Android Studio and its Flutter/Dart plug-ins

Now I can start up Android Studio and pick an emulator (by default "no device connected" shows), hit run and the emulator works but if I go to my command line here is what I get and I followed it up with 'flutter emulators' 'flutter doctor'

When I tell it to check for emulators it tells me "To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch '"
Where do i find the ID?

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Computer Science\Flutter Projects\first_app>flutter 
run
No connected devices.

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Computer Science\Flutter Projects\first_app>flutter 
emulators
2 available emulators:

Nexus_5X_API_28_x86 • Nexus 5X • Google • Nexus 5X API 28 x86
Nexus_6P            • Nexus 6P • Google • Nexus 6P

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Computer Science\Flutter Projects\first_app>flutter 
doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
10.0.17134.285], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 27):

Try this to start your emulator then you will se connected devices.
Once you have running emulator try running flutter app.
Right now you dont have any emulator running thays why its telling you No connected devices...

```
flutter emulators --launch Nexus_6P
```

Comment: Do you know how to make this happen automatically if the device isn't run in the launch.json file?

Answer (score 10):

Step 1: Go to the project folder in which you have created the flutter project in cmd (using `cd Root/of/your/project`)

Step 2: Run the following commands:

```
flutter emulators --create <whateverIdYouLike>
(Eg:- For my project I used `flutter emulators --create Nexus_6`)
```

This should give you the message:

> "Emulator [Name] created successfully.'

Step 3: Type in the following command:

```
flutter emulators
```

You will see an emulator has been added successfully.

Step 4: Launch the emulator using the following command:

```
flutter emulators --launch <emulator id> //in my case, the id of the newly created emulator was "flutter_emulator"
```

For further info check
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager

Comment: I created the Emulator using the command `flutter emulators --create Nexus_6` then in the command `flutter emulators` i can see 2 emulators `Nexus_6` and `flutter_emulator` but when I run the `flutter doctor` i still only get 3 ticks and the `connected device no device available`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run app in your connect device through flutter, then first get the device name or id by typing 
`flutter devices` 
It will give you info 
[image]

And run the app by running this command

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) on your system then connect it with mobile through USB cable now the mobile screen will be mirrored on the system, and will act as emulator.